# wsimport result has a different runtime endpoint

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, endpoint, wsimport

This is an odd one.

I'm generating client code for a soap service using a wsimport plugin for maven like this...

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                  <wsdlUrl>${testWsdlLocationUrl}</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <destDir>${basedir}/target/jaxws</destDir>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...where I've parameterised the external wsdlUrl. I can see where the wsdl url (fudged for anonymity) is defined in the generated client like this...

```
static {
    URL url = null;

    try {
        URL e = SpecialService.class.getResource(".");
        url = new URL(e, "http://theUrlThatIDefinedAbove:withTheCorrectPortNumber/blahblah?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException var2) {
        logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: \'http://theUrlThatIDefinedAbove:withTheCorrectPortNumber/blahblah?wsdl\', retrying as a local file");
        logger.warning(var2.getMessage());
    }

    SPECIALSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

...so all looks fine so far. The build creates a jar containing only the compiled code generated from wsimport.

However, when I refer to this generated client in my code to call the service, the endpoint is different! Here's (the gist of) what I do...

```
this.serviceEndpoint = new SpecialService().getSpecialServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint();
```

this.serviceEndpoint.callTheSpecialMethodOnTheService(withSomeDataOrOther)

Simple enough eh? However, I get a timeout exception.

When I look at the service endpoint like this:

```
System.out.println("Service Endpoint : " + this.serviceEndpoint.toString());
```

I get (something like)...

```
Service Endpoint : JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01: Stub for http://theCorrectUrlHere:8080/withTheCorrectPath/
```

...where did 8080 come from? It's not on the wsdl url I specified.

Curiously if I manually change the service endpoint like this...
    ((BindingProvider)this.serviceEndpoint).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "theCorrectUrlAndPort")

...everything works fine and I can happily access the remote service.

Have I missed something obvious? I assumed that giving wsimport the wsdl location would bake the correct endpoint into the client code, and it certainly looks that way with the host and path data being correct but the port being wrong.

Have I done something foolish with the wsimport plugin perhaps? Do I need to supply the port in wsimport perhaps?

I would be grateful for any suggestions you can provide.

EDIT

Following Leo's suggestion, here's the new plugin config...

```
<testWsdlLocationUrl>http://editedOutHost:portThatIsNot8080/the/rest/of/the/path?wsdl</testWsdlLocationUrl>
```

...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-stubs</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>${testWsdlLocationUrl}</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlLocation>${testWsdlLocationUrl}</wsdlLocation>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Please note it is pointing to a remote wsdl location rather than a local one in your commented example.

The change of plugin generates the classes in the same way as in my original question, on decompilation both point to the correct host port and path, and both still exhibit the same problem of defaulting the port back to 8080.

*** UPDATED ***

The same problem occurs when I manually run wsimport from the command line and jar up the resulting classes, so I don't think the use of maven is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm answering my own question. I'm doing this for the benefit of anyone of experiences this problem in the future.

I've just heard back from the guys hosting the service I've been trying to connect to with the mysteriously changing port.

Their server "...is running on our internal network on ports 8080 and 8443 and is made externally reachable using a NAT with port translations. Thus, the ports shown in the WSDL files are those (un)known by the server."

So there we have it. The ports available for grabbing wsdls might not be available for service calls. Isn't that odd?

Answer (score 0):

Try using codehaus plugin, will be useful to sort the issues related wsdl location

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-wsdl</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsgen</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sei><!-- fully qualified class name goes here --></sei>
                    <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-stubs</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>target/jaxws/wsgen/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>                   
                        <wsdlFile><!-- class name goes here -->Service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <!-- *** you need the next line to set the wsdlLocation in the generated stubs *** -->
                    <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/test</wsdlLocation> 
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I'll try. The example you give is assuming a local wsdl, so I'll swap out the wsdlFile/Directory nodes for wsdlUrls. I've also tried generating the classes using wsimport from the command line rather than through maven, so the maven plugin I use might not be relevant, but I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: ...hang on, am I missing something here? Why would I want to generate a wsdl? Are you suggesting I take the generated source I have, generate a wsdl from it, then regenerate the code?

Comment: Use wsimport execution alone for generating the client from specified wsdl.

Comment: Ok, here's the updated plugin config following your suggestion... I'll add something to the question.

Comment: you can better make the stub end point configurable, getting the wsdl end point address and port in run time, so for different environments you can simply change url configuration in your property file and the same url can be set in stub service class dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate you are pointing out the positive sides of defining the end point at run time (i.e. that it is configurable for different environments), but the whole purpose of creating the client using wsimport is so that the client requires no further configuration. I want to create a client jar with everything set up in it to point to one place, give it to someone else and say "There you go! No more configuration is required.". If there's an alternative location, I can supply a different jar.

Comment: I tried for a sample wsdl running ws import from command line and i am able to successfully generate the client with the wsdl location which i specified. `wsimport -keep -d "D:\Cxf wsimport" -target 2.1 -verbose "PhoneBookWSDL.wsdl" -wsdllocation http://10.90.1.1:8088/phoneservice/PhoneBookService`

Comment: client stub service class url location in code `url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://10.90.1.1:8088/phoneservice/PhoneBookService");
        } `

Comment: I experience the same. My client stub service class points to the correct location. I mention this in my original post. However, when I call the stub from code it reverts to port to 8080. It is this unexpected behaviour in this case that prompted me to post question, asking whether anyone has experienced this odd behaviour.